# CMD is not openning from any folder

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

i entered cmd from a folder in address bar it is working fine a month ago, but rightnow it is not working, please help. the cmd is not opening from any folder but working fine from window(start) -> cmd
also i'm using as admin itself

[i had entered cmd and pressed enter too, but not openning cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVoZw.png)

Comment: I didn't even know you could do this. Have an attempt at this, and then examine the event viewer. You might be able to get a clue to the cause there.

Comment: Not really an answer, hence a comment but I think you'd find this helpful - https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-176-CMD-and-PowerShell-Context-Menus benefit being you can choose an elevated CMD/PS window.

Comment: Can you open cmd by win+R ? Have you try this use another account?

Comment: So nothing happens? No error that the destination is not known or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If that way didn't help you can try `cd 'your path'` in cmd which you can open using windows + R and writing cmd in the input or by searching in windows menu

or you can try writing `cmd.exe` instead it may help

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the environment variables. If its defined under system variables section.

Go to Settings->system Properties->Advanced Tab

On the bottom right you will find the Environment variables .

If system variable is not defined for command prompt , you would need to add that

Click on New-> Give variable name as what you want to name it and variable past as path to the executable , in this case if its cmd.exe.

*Mostly the path of cmd.exe is C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

Comment: Nope, there doesn’t need to be a system variable that leads directly to cmd.exe. I don‘t have one directly and it works. 
But it might be that the path must be in %PATH% which seems to be the case for OP.